# Insert file into Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Is it possible for us to insert a file in Angular? I have already created an HTML/CSS/Bootstrap website but the problem is, I wasn't able to create one thru Angular. Is it possible to put the one I created in Angular? If its possible, how?

I have tried inserting it and it worked for the HTML file but the CSS is not working. It doesn't read the CSS and the bootstrap which is inside a folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a component.

If you have Angular CLI installed:
**In the project folder**

`ng g c componentname`
or
`ng generate component componentname`

If you dont have Angilar CLI installed:
`npm i -g @angular/cli`

Then copy your css and html the the component

Comment: Do I have to add components such as importing it?

Comment: if you have the html and css file, just copy the content in it

Comment: Hello, how do I import my CSS to Component?

Comment: Can you send the components ts file?

Comment: Give me an hour as I am outside atm.

Comment: I haven't created a component yet due to I am confused on how will I input the codes on the component if I have to use import